# Left USB in laptop, placed in case with the weight on the USB

Tags: usb, port, microsoft-surface

I packed my Surface Pro 4 in my laptop sleeve and placed it in my backpack vertically with the USB ports at the bottom (to protect the pen). I opened the sleeve to find a USB was still there. I am just wondering if there are any effects to the USB port. I have tried multiple USB's and they work but I don't want to take chances.

Comment: This is not opinion-based. The user is worried about potential damage and does not know how to be sure whether or not there is any.

Comment: That's fair, rescinded.

Comment: USB Mouse Reciever - Not a Nano - looks like a USB thumb drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only damage would be physical, and the physical damage would be visible or evident in loose connections.

So if there is no visible physical damage and the port appears to be sound, you're probably OK.

Comment: Thanks that puts my mind at ease. How can I check if the port appears sound?

Comment: Are USB devices plugged into this port looser than they were before?

Is there any visible damage to the port?

These are the two primary ways to check for damage.

Comment: USB's plugs in normally and the computer reads and autoruns fine, and the port looks normal.

Comment: Consider yourself fortunate. :)